# Trouble with converting a String into a Joda DateTime object

Tags: java, date, file-io, jodatime

Trouble with converting a String into a Joda DateTime object.  I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  I am following instructions on other threads here on StackOverflow, but the following code does not work.  It throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberFormatter.parseInto(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:1330)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$Composite.parseInto(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2741)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:853)
    at co.restclient.ExpiringCookie.<init>(ExpiringCookie.java:41)
    at co.restclient.ExpiringCookie.main(ExpiringCookie.java:29)
```

And here is the code.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Duration;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

/*
 * This class stores a cookie value and can tell when its expired by its timestamp
 */
public class ExpiringCookie {   

    public static DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss" );
    public static File cookieJar = new File("cookie.xml");
    public String singleCookie;
    DateTime startTime;
    DateTime currentTime;
    boolean isExpired = false;

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ExpiringCookie ec = new ExpiringCookie( "xxxxxxx" );
        System.out.println( "Age of cookie: " + ec.timePassed().getMillis() );
    }

    public ExpiringCookie( String cookie ) {
        currentTime = new DateTime();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        if ( cookieJar.exists() ) {
            try {
                properties.load( new FileInputStream( cookieJar ) );                
                new DateTime();
                //startTime = DateTime.parse( properties.getProperty( "startTime" ), DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss" ) );
                startTime = fmt.parseDateTime( properties.getProperty( "startTime" ) );
                singleCookie = properties.getProperty( "cookie" );
            } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {            
            properties.setProperty( "startTime", fmt.print( currentTime ) );
            properties.setProperty( "cookie", cookie );
            startTime = new DateTime( currentTime.plusSeconds(-1) );
            try {
                properties.storeToXML( new FileOutputStream( cookieJar ), "Stores cookie for API requests" );
            } catch ( FileNotFoundException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch ( IOException e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public Duration timePassed() {      
        return new Duration( startTime, currentTime );
    }

    public boolean isExpired() {
        return isExpired;
    }

}
```

The cookie.xml file content is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>Stores cookie for API requests</comment>
<entry key="cookie">xxxxxxx</entry>
<entry key="startTime">03/01/2014 10:00:08</entry>
</properties>
```

Comment: what is the result of properties.getProperty( "startTime" ) and what version of joda time do you use?

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `properties.getProperty( "startTime" )` in line 41 seems to return `null`.

Check the JavaDoc for [Properties#getProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29)

It says

> Searches for the property with the specified key in this property list. If the key is not found in this property list, the default property list, and its defaults, recursively, are then checked. The method returns null if the property is not found.

So there seems to be no value for the key `startTime` in the file `data/cookie.xml`

I assume that you use the latest joda time version 2.3. [In line 1330](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.3/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java/#1330) `text.length()` gets called. If, as I assume above, `properties.getProperty( "startTime" )` returns null, you get the NPE.

**Solution:** Make sure there is a value for the key `startTime` in file `data/cookie.xml`

Comment: Im just using the regular Properties   to/from xml  methods.  Shouldn't they be reliable?  If you run the program I provided above, I am not seeing where I could have made a mistake like that.

Comment: What is the value of startTime in the file data/cookie.xml? Did you check?

Comment: Try to use the Properties#loadFromXML method instead of Properties#load http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML%28java.io.InputStream%29 Does that make any difference?

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
fmt.parseDateTime(null);
```

produces a NPE, see this similar stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$NumberFormatter.parseIntoDateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:1292)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder$Composite.parseInto(DateTimeFormatterBuilder.java:2695)
    at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseDateTime(DateTimeFormatter.java:846)
    at time.JodaTest8.main(JodaTest8.java:80)
```

And the [javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseDateTime%28java.lang.String%29) says that the argument must not be null.

**General remark:** It is very bad that you just create file streams without closing them after use. Maybe this is the cause of your problem. The file might already have been created in a former run, but is not yet finished/flushed/closed. And then you ask for the property values in this file, a NPE is then easily possible! So please fix your stream problem.

Comment: Your right. properties.getProperty() is pulling a null value from the properties file that it wrote itself.  I dont see how that is possible.

Comment: @djangofan I have added a possible scenario why there was no property in your cookie test. And try to be consistent, `storeToXML()` should be paired by `loadFromXML()`, not `load()`.